# Criar Model a partir de uma Migração

Tags: laravel, mvc

Eu criei migrations a partir do comando `migrate:generate` da dependência https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Existe alguma forma de gerar models a partir dessas migrações?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dei uma olhada, e pelo visto não tem não.
O atributo `name` do comando que fica no arquivo `MigrateGenerateCommand.php` somente exibe o valor `migrate:generate`. Normalmente, se houvesse mais alguma opção adicional nessa geração de migrations, esse atributo estabeleceria qual é.

À princípio, dei uma olhada nesse outro repositório que possa fazer o mesmo com Models, e encontrei esse aqui: https://github.com/reliese/laravel.

Ele monta um *scaffolding* completo a partir de um banco de dados e/ou tabela específica. No arquivo de configurações dele (dentro da pasta `/config`, logo após a instalação) dá pra você setar se é pra gerar a Model com timestamps, soft deletes, etc.

Comment: Muito bom, cara... Obrigadão!